# ExecuteNonQuery throwing invalidCastException

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm just trying to do a simple update to the database and I get an exception I don't understand.

Here is the code - help please:

```
protected void btnmodif_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AGENDAConnectionString2"].ConnectionString );

   SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
   sqlComm = sqlConn.CreateCommand();

   sqlComm.CommandText = @"UPDATE RDV SET STATUES_COM = @STAT_COM WHERE INDICE = @ind";

   sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@STAT_COM", SqlDbType.VarChar);
   sqlComm.Parameters["@STAT_COM"].Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

   sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@ind", SqlDbType.VarChar);
   sqlComm.Parameters["@ind"].Value = Request.QueryString["Champ"].ToString();

   sqlConn.Open();
   sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
   sqlConn.Close();

   Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('SUCCESS');</script>");
}
```

I updated the code

Comment: Well what's the exception? Always, always give the full exception details (stack trace, message, nested exceptions).

Comment: But aside from anything else, you shouldn't have the parameters in quotes - you want `SET STATUES_COM=@STAT_CONM WHERE INDICE=@ind` for example. Also, `Parameters.Add` returns the parameter, so you can just use `sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@ind", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Request.QueryString[...];` - it makes the code a lot simpler that way.,

Comment: use the debugger and tell us what the value is here `DropDownList1.SelectedItem` and you should be capturing the `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text`

Comment: the exception was because  of the DropDownList1.SelectedItem i used this  DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text and i no longuer get that exception but there is no changes in the database ...

Comment: @Jon Skeet  i did what u suggested and removed the parameter codes and still not working

Comment: @OussemaM'zoughi have you used the debugger to step through the code.. what is the value of the connection string, what is the value of `Request.QueryString["Champ"].ToString(); ;` you don't need the extra `;` at the end of this line won't correct the issue.. also tell us what the errors are that you are having..?  I am going to refactor your code and recommend that you using this approach in the answer I will post.

Comment: Well you haven't changed the code in your question, and it still says you get an exception, so it's kinda hard to help you. Have you fixed the part where the parameter names are quoted in the SQL?

Comment: I get No error Data base is simply not apdated  i printed Request.QueryString["Champ"].ToString(); it Shows 1 exactly what i need and the dropdowlist.selecteditems.text prints  "rdv(conf)" wich is the value of the selected item wich is what i need

Comment: yes i did @jon skeet i also updated the Code

Comment: And have you checked that there *are* some rows where `INDICE = @ind`? It's hard to tell with no idea of your request string or the data in the database...

Comment: yes i checked  and @ind is the query sTring  i can see it in the page url

Comment: Jon Skeet is not asking what the value is in the URL you need to tell us what the value is when you put a break point in your code and step through the code when you use the `QuickWatch` or add to the `watcher` what the value of the querystring is..

Comment: yes whe i add a print Line 

      Response.Write(@"<script  language='javascript'>alert('"+Request.QueryString["Champ"].ToString();+"');</script>");

it prints the value that means it's working no ?

Comment: what is the value is it `abcd` or `10`..etc this is what we mean .. we are not asking about how you are printing or capturing it we want the actual value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your button click event replace your code with this

```
protected void btnmodif_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var wasSuccessful = UpDateDB();
   if(wasSuccessful)
   {
      //Do Something 
   }
   else
   {
     //Do Something Else logging etc...
   }
}

public static bool UpDateDB()
{
    var ConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AGENDAConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
    bool successful = false;
    var ddlSelectedText = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    var strUpdate = "UPDATE RDV SET STATUES_COM = @STAT_COM WHERE INDICE = @ind"; 

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strUpdate, connection))
        {
            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STAT_COM", ddlSelectedText);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ind", (string)Request.QueryString["Champ"]);
            sqlComm.CommandTimeout = 120;
            sqlComm.Connection.Open();
            try
            {
                sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                successful = true;
            }
            catch(SqlException SqlEx)
            {
                successful = false;
                //Write to a long SqlEx.Message
            }
        }
    }
    return successful;
}
```

Comment: im trying this @methot man ty

Comment: thank you  so much  @Method Man that works i had to remove static from
     public static bool UpDateDB()
and change this 
    (string)Request.QueryString["Champ"]
to this
Request.QueryString["Champ"].ToString()

but it worked  you're a life savour